# Seleccionar registros que no sean NULL dentro de un CASE

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

Pueden ayudarme con lo siguiente, actualmente tengo una consulta de una tabla de [sql-server](/questions/tagged/sql-server) la cual me trae los registros dependiendo de una condición en el `WHERE` y clasifica dichos registros en 4 categorías las cuales son '`Contrato`', '`Otrosies`', '`Garantias`' y '`Polizas`'. Ésto lo realizo a través de la función `CASE`, el nombre de la categoría la almaceno en una columna extra la cual la función `CASE` me da la posibilidad de crear, dicha columna le asigne el nombre "`CLASIFICACION`",

Los registros son clasificados con éxito en las categorías mencionadas anteriormente pero el problema que tengo es que necesito que mi consulta solo me traiga los registros que se encuentren dentro de estas 4 categorías, ya que al encontrar registros que no cumplen dichas condiciones en el `CASE`, en mi columna extra "`CLASIFICACION`" les asigna el valor `NULL` y también me trae dichos registros.

Aquí mi query:

```
SELECT 
       TituloDocumento,                                                                                      TipoDocumentoAcuerdo,
       Contenido,
       CLASIFICACION=
       CASE 
       WHEN
       TipoDocumentoAcuerdo IN ('CONTRATO','CONTRATO E＆P', 'CONTRATOS CON SOCIOS') THEN 'CONTRATO'
       WHEN
       TipoDocumentoAcuerdo = ('OTROSIES') THEN 'OTROSIES'
       WHEN
       TipoDocumentoAcuerdo = ('GARANTÍAS') THEN 'GARANTÍAS'
       WHEN
       TipoDocumentoAcuerdo = ('GARANTÍAS') AND TituloDocumento LIKE ('%POLIZA%') THEN 'POLIZAS'
       END
       FROM reporte_documentos_Tecnicos
       WHERE Contenido = ('Acuerdos de Gobierno')
```

Muchas gracias por su ayuda.

Comment: No entiendo que necesitas, quieres que le lleve un NULL a los que no cumplen la condicion ? o simplemnte que no le lleve nada si no cumple la condicion ?,

Comment: Creo que tú solución es añadir en el where AND CLASIFICACION IS NOT NULL

Comment: Creo que lo que necesitas es agregar en el where --> AND TipoDocumentoAcuerdo IN ('CONTRATO','CONTRATO E＆P', 'CONTRATOS CON SOCIOS', 'OTROSIES', 'GARANTÍAS')

Comment: Hola srJJ, necesito que me traiga únicamente los registros que estén dentro de las 4 categorías, cuando los registros no se encuentran en alguna categoría en mi columna extra "CLASIFICACION" se coloca como NULL y necesito que me muestre los registros cuando mi columna extra "CLASIFICACION" no sea de tipo NULL.

Comment: Hola Jakala, mi columna "CLASIFICACION" no pertenece a la tabla reporte_documentos_Tecnicos, esta columna la cree gracias a la función CASE la cual me da la posibilidad de crear una columna extra por lo tanto si le adiciono en el where 
FROM reporte_documentos_Tecnicos
WHERE Contenido = ('Acuerdos de Gobierno') AND CLASIFICACION IS NOT NULL 
me genera un error diciendo que la columna CLASIFICACION no es valida.
Gracias por tu ayuda.

Comment: puedes poner algo representativo de lo que existe y de lo que quieres ver en tu resultado?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

siguiendo el consejo de Francisco si agregaba en el `where` la condicion `AND` `TipoDocumentoAcuerdo` `IS NOT NULL`, la columna CLASIFICACION me seguia arrojando resultados con valor `NULL`, al final se pudo solucionar gracias al usuario Luis Gutierrez quien me sugirio que en el `where` le agregara la `condicion AND TipoDocumentoAcuerdo IN ('CONTRATO','CONTRATO E＆P', 'CONTRATOS CON SOCIOS', 'OTROSIES', 'GARANTÍAS')` por lo cual la consulta quedo

```
SELECT 
       TituloDocumento,                                                          
       TipoDocumentoAcuerdo,
       Contenido,
       CLASIFICACION=
       CASE 
       WHEN
       TipoDocumentoAcuerdo IN ('CONTRATO','CONTRATO E＆P', 'CONTRATOS CON SOCIOS') THEN 'CONTRATO'
       WHEN
       TipoDocumentoAcuerdo = ('OTROSIES') THEN 'OTROSIES'
       WHEN
       TipoDocumentoAcuerdo = ('GARANTÍAS') THEN 'GARANTÍAS'
       WHEN
       TipoDocumentoAcuerdo = ('GARANTÍAS') AND TituloDocumento LIKE ('%POLIZA%') THEN 'POLIZAS'
       END
       FROM reporte_documentos_Tecnicos
       WHERE Contenido = ('Acuerdos de Gobierno')
AND TipoDocumentoAcuerdo IN ('CONTRATO','CONTRATO E＆P', 'CONTRATOS CON SOCIOS', 'OTROSIES', 'GARANTÍAS') 

y en los resultados la columna CLASIFICACION ya me trae los valores que cumplen las condiciones en el case, es decir 'CONTRATO' - 'OTROSIES' - 'GARANTÍAS' y 'POLIZAS'.
```

Answer (score 2):

Aumentale una condicion al **`where`** para que omita los resultados **`null`**:

```
       SELECT 
       TituloDocumento,                                                                                      TipoDocumentoAcuerdo,
       Contenido,
       CLASIFICACION=
       CASE 
       WHEN
       TipoDocumentoAcuerdo IN ('CONTRATO','CONTRATO E＆P', 'CONTRATOS CON SOCIOS') THEN 'CONTRATO'
       WHEN
       TipoDocumentoAcuerdo = ('OTROSIES') THEN 'OTROSIES'
       WHEN
       TipoDocumentoAcuerdo = ('GARANTÍAS') THEN 'GARANTÍAS'
       WHEN
       TipoDocumentoAcuerdo = ('GARANTÍAS') AND TituloDocumento LIKE ('%POLIZA%') THEN 'POLIZAS'
       END
       FROM reporte_documentos_Tecnicos
       WHERE Contenido = ('Acuerdos de Gobierno') AND TipoDocumentoAcuerdo IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Por favor agrega una descripción a tu respuesta. Lee 
**[cómo escribo una buena respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)**.